# How to pass an anonymous object to a generic method with multiple generic types?

Tags: c#, types, generic-method, anonymous-objects

Let's say I have this generic method:

```
public T1 GenericTest<T1, T2>(T2 Obj, out T2 NewObj)
{
    NewObj = Obj;
    return default;
}
```

How do I pass an anonymous object to it?

What do I put in place of the "???" when calling the method in the following example:

```
var Anonymous = new { Prop1 = "foo", Prop2 = "bar" };
GenericTest<bool,???>(Anonymous, out var NewAnonymous);
NewAnonymous.Prop1 = "Hello";
NewAnonymous.Prop2 = "World";
//etc...
```

My goal is to have Visual Studio's Intellisense pick up "Prop1" and "Prop2" on the "NewAnonymous" object after I call the method. This requires the anonymous type to be inferred, but I don't know how to do it with multiple type specifiers.

NOTE: I want to be able to access the properties of the anonymous object that is returned from the "out" parameter, **so type "object" will not be good enough**. If I put "object" as the type, I won't be able to access the properties "Prop1" and "Prop2" on the "NewAnonymous" object from outside the method.

NOTE 2: I do not need to access the properties of the anonymous object from within the method.

---

EDIT: Anonymous objects can indeed be passed to generic methods. I just don't know how to do it with a generic method with multiple type specifiers (which is why I made this question). Here is an example with just one type specifier:

```
public void SingleGenericTypeTest<T>(T Obj, out T NewObj)
{
    NewObj = Obj;
}
var Anonymous = new { Prop1 = "foo", Prop2 = "bar" };
SingleGenericTypeTest(Anonymous, out var NewAnonymous);
NewAnonymous.Prop1 = "Hello";
NewAnonymous.Prop2 = "World";
//etc...
```

Comment: Anonymous types _have_ no name at compile time, so you can't use their "name" as a generic argument. In addition, you won't be able to call `CreateInstance` since anonymous types don't have parameterless constructors. You'll need to explain exactly why you need to create an instance. Or explain what you're _trying_ to do and we can help with an actual solution.

Comment: @DStanley I removed the CreateInstance call since it's not relevant to the question

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem that you can;t use anonymous types as generic arguments. Why do you need to access the properties? IF the method is generic you won't know what type is being passed in, so you won't know its properties anyways.

Comment: @DStanley You can use anonymous types as generic arguments. I know how to do it when there is just one type argument, just not with multiple. I just put an example in the question.

Comment: _"If I put "object" as the type, I won't be able to access the properties "Prop1" and "Prop2" on the "NewAnonymous" object"_ -- your question is unclear. While anonymous types can be passed to generic methods, and even be passed in a way that the generic type is _inferred_, there is never going to be a way you can pass an instance of an anonymous type in a way that allows the method to directly access specific _properties_ in the anonymous type explicitly. Please fix your question so it does a better job of explaining exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: As an example of just how broken your question is, look at this code "example": `GenericTest<bool,???>(Anonymous, out var NewAnonymous);`. You have explicitly specified the type parameter `bool` for `T1` but you don't use that type parameter in the method anywhere, other than to return `default`. What use is that? Anonymous types and type inference for generic methods go hand in hand, but you can't have the compiler infer only some of the types, and it can't infer something that's only a return type. So it's not clear at all what that example is supposed to be an example _of_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I don't need to access the properties of the object from within the method. I added a little more clarification to the question.

Comment: _"I don't need to access the properties of the object from within the method"_ -- so is it just the partial inference you're having trouble with?

Comment: @PeterDuniho The method is a dummy method (a test method if you will). I am only returning T1 to demonstrate my question, it's the concept of doing it that I am asking about

Comment: something like `Chainer Build<T2>(T2 fake){ return new Chainer<T2>()}; class Chainer<T2>{ T1 Call<T1>(T2 input, out T2 result){ return GenericTest<T1, T2>(input, out result);}`

Comment: @user3163495 You're right, I misspoke - you can't _specify_ an anonymous type as a generic argument. You can certainly let the compiler infer it for you. If not being able to infer the `bool` (and thus not the anonymous type)  is you're problem, there are a few ways around that.

Comment: Also note that anonymous types are immutable, so `NewAnonymous.Prop1 = "Hello";` won't work. Again, please state what you're trying to accomplish, not just how to shoehorn what you _want_ to do into what you _need_ to do.

Answer (score 0):

Type inference requires that **all** generic types be inferred. If your method took an argument of type `T1` you could then elide the types. Unfortunately you can't do that here since no parameter of the first type exists and there's no way to specify the *unspeakable* anonymous type.

The best you are going to get is a helper method with one generic argument that passes through to the second, specifying both types:

```cs
public bool GenericHelper<T>(T Obj, out T NewObj)
{
    return GenericTest<bool, T>(Obj, out NewObj);
}

public T1 GenericTest<T1, T2>(T2 Obj, out T2 NewObj)
{
    NewObj = Obj;
    return default;
}
```

Which you can then use:

```cs
var Anonymous = new { Prop1 = "foo", Prop2 = "bar" };
bool res = GenericHelper(Anonymous, out var NewAnonymous);
```

Though it still doesn't make much sense that you want to do this.